# How to declare custom props to RequestHandler in express js middleware functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have an error handling middleware which handles the errors in my express app like this :

```
export const errorMiddleware = (app: Application): void => {
  // If the route is not correct
  app.use(((req, res, next): void => {
    const error: any = new Error("Route not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
    logger.error(`${error.status} ${error.message}`);
  }) as RequestHandler);
  // If any operation fail and throw error with next will come here
  app.use(((error, req, res, next): void => {
    logger.error(`${error.status} ${error.message}`);
    res.status(error.status || 500).json({
      error: {
        message: error.message,
      },
      status: error.status || 500,
    });
  }) as RequestHandler);
};
```

The first `app.use` passes an error object to the next middleware which gets that error object in the first parameter :

```
 app.use(((error, req, res, next): void => {
```

Now I've declared a `RequestHandler` type for it and it gives error because of that custom first parameter it gets which is error .

[image]

How can I use the RequestHandler prop with one extra prop type added to it so I can fix this error ?

Comment: Use the ErrorRequestHandler? But you'd be better not using type assertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not introduce new parameters in a callback function like that, it just accepts fixed parameters and in that order. So your `error` parameter will contain `req`!

To pass data from one middleware to the next middlewares, use `res.locals`.

Take a look at http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals

You should set it in your first middleware like this:

```
res.locals.error = 'Sorry'
```

And you can use it in the next middlewares like this:

```
if (res.locals.err) {...}
```

It's persisted in the request's lifecycle.